# zxing barcode scanning fragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am very new to mobile development and I trying to make an android app using Xamarin(visual studio). I am trying to integrate zxing barcode scanner into my app and I have found many examples of it's integration into app but they are all using Activity. I want to use fragments instead of Activity. I tried to make my fragment and the scanning screen do come up but it is not scanning anything. Can someone please point into the right direction. Thank you.

**Updated file**
Here is my **Fragment2.cs**:

```
public class Fragment2 : Fragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MySettingsView, container, false);



        ImageButton scanBtn = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnScan);
        TextView results = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.results);

        scanBtn.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Activity.Application);
            var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
            var result = await scanner.Scan();

            if (result != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Scanned Barcode: {result}");
            Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                results.Text = result.Text;
            });
        };

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am changing a few things:

```
public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // you don't need this you can safely remove it.
    //var ignored = base.OnCreateView (inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    // changed this line to properly inflate the fragment's layout 
    var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.fragment2_layout, container, false);

    ImageButton scanBtn = view.FindViewById<ImageButton> (Resource.Id. btnScan);
    TextView results = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id. Results);

    scanBtn.Click += async (sender, e) => {

        // you don not create a new instance of the Android Application 
       // but get the one already created. From an activity you 
      // just call `Application` but from inside a fragment you need to get 
      // the fragment's activity then get the Application.

        MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize (Activity.Application);

        var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner ();

        var result = await scanner.Scan ();

        // The if was inverted.
        if (result == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine ($"Scanned Barcode: {result}");

        // Using this you are sure it will run in the UI thread
        // as you will be updating an UI element.
        Activity.RunOnUiThread (() => {
            results.Text = result.Text;
        });

    };

    return view;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your code, the camera gets on but it is scanning nothing. Also nothing is coming up in console window.

Comment: Did you add the permissions for the camera and the flashlight?

Comment: yes I did add the permissions. It worked once and it is not working anymore. Also when it did worked the result wasn't showing up in the textview "results".

Comment: Update the original post with the code of your Fragment2 `OnCreateView` method with the updates.

Comment: I have edited the post with the updated `OnCreateView` method

Comment: Here's your issue:   `if (result != null)` it should be `if (result == null)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145913/discussion-between-nick-king-and-apineda).

Answer (score 1):

@apineda's code work perfectly but I was having the auto-focusing issues. After doing so research, I found a work around to that problem. Here is my scanning fragment.

```
public class Fragment2 : Fragment
{
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MySettingsView, container, false);



    ImageButton scanBtn = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnScan);
    TextView results = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.results);

    scanBtn.Click += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Activity.Application);
        var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
        var result = (ZXing.Result)null;

        result = await scanner.Scan();

        if (result == null)
        {
            scanner.AutoFocus();
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Scanned Barcode: {result}");
        Activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            results.Text = result.Text;
        });
    };

    return view;
}
}
```